# Using Case Statement to match multiple values on single row

Tags: sql-server

I'm and trying to create a view which includes data from multiple tables. Where I am stuck is when trying to use a CASE Statement to return a Yes or No answer.  I want to query the entire row and only return the Yes answer if both values match on the single row.

TABLE employees

| EmpCode | FirstName | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Chris | Kite |
| 002 | Mark | Flowers |
| 003 | Kate | Aid |

TABLE areas

| EmpCode | Area | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1 | am |
| 001 | 1 | pm |
| 001 | 2 | pm |
| 002 | 1 | am |
| 003 | 2 | am |

My CASE Statement is

```
CASE
  WHEN areas.area = '1' AND areas.time = 'am'
    THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
  END AS CanWork
```

I am expecting to see in the result

| EmpCode | CanWork |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Yes |
| 002 | No |
| 003 | No |

however its returning

| EmpCode | Can Work |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Yes |
| 001 | Yes |
| 001 | No |
| 002 | Yes |
| 003 | Yes |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your areas query by emp_code. Or apply WHERE EXISTS construction. [Here's the example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNyavx4B81mKfyrNW4vrR1/0).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the logic in your current `CASE` expression just belongs in a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT EmpCode, FirstName, Surname
FROM areas
WHERE area = '1' AND time = 'am';
```

Note that if there could be more one matching record for each `EmpCode`, then use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: I should have expanded the post a bit more, this is just part of the wider query - so only a small number of employees will have data in the area table. By putting it in the WHERE clause, it only shows the people that it matches with - but i need the result to be a yes or no.
It should actually be returning

| EmpCode | Area      | Time    | CanWork  |
| -------        | ---------    | -------    | -------------- |
| 001     | 1         | am      | yes |
| 002     | 1         | am      | yes |
| 003     | 2         | am      | no |

Comment: That's not the question you asked or the data you showed us.  You might want to ask the actual question now.